# Issues with display multiple images

Tags: django, django-forms, django-uploads

I want to display images which are stored in database.

If I used this. 
in **view**
    product = Upload_files.objects.get(id=1)

and in **form**

```
<img src="/media/{{ form.image }}/" />
```

then it will show the image of **id=1** . But if I want to display all images from database what should I do for that.

I used this in view(not sure it is right)

```
product = Upload_files.objects.all()
```

but I don't know what should I write in my form, so that it display all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab all the products int he view then loop over them in the template.

// View

```
products = Upload_files.objects.all()
```

// Template

```
{% for product in products %}
    <img src="/media/{{ product.image }}/" />
{% endfor %}
```